# How do I build and install PL/Python against a custom Postgresql (e.g. PG_CONFIG)?

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython, pipelinedb

I am using PipelineDB, which is a customized, yet compatible fork of Postgresql.  I want to install the plpythonu.control into it to be able to use the PL/Python for user-defined functions.

I am supposed to "build" the plpythonu extension against the PipelineDB installation, but I cannot find the plpythonu sourcecode nor find any instructions on how to 'make' or 'build' it. Can somebody point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the provider of your PipelineDB distribution should also provide the `contrib` package, so the correct answer depends on how your PipelineDB got installed.
If this is not the case ([seems it is not](https://github.com/pipelinedb/pipelinedb/issues/1645%20seems)): `plpythonu` is a PostgreSQL contrib package, and its source code is part of the PostgreSQL source code, and of any fork's source code as well. A simple Google search for `pipelinedb plpythonu` reveals the location of pipelinedb source on the GitHub. Generally, you clone the source for your version of PipelineDB, and then

```
cd src/pl/plpython
make
make install
```

Probably it's a bit more complicated than that; [here's a PipelineDB build script for Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=pipelinedb) which handles these.